# How do I extract exact html content in python using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I'm a beginner in scrapy and I'm not able to get the exact `html` content to extract the required divisions.

How do I extract exact html content in python using `scrapy`? I have tried using `requests` library and `scrapy` request as well. But not able to get the exact HTML content of the page. I want to use `scrapy` in `Spyder / Jupiter` Notebook.

Tried through following different requests, but it's not working.

```
# My Code:

import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = 'https://www.rbauction.com/construction?cid=3279191388',
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)


from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()
process.stop()
```

#

```
import requests
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
import scrapy

url = 'https://www.rbauction.com/construction?cid=3279191388'
a = scrapy.Request(url)
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
a = HtmlResponse(url)
a.xpath('//*[@id="rba--category-page"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[6]/a').extract()
```

#

```
import requests
import json
from lxml import html
import requests
source = requests.get("https://www.rbauction.com/construction?cid=3279191388")
tree = html.fromstring(source.content)
```

#

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
url = "https://www.rbauction.com/construction?cid=3279191388"
f = opener.open(url)
content = f.read()
```

#

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "quotes"
     def start_requests(self):
           url = [
               'https://www.rbauction.com/construction?cid=3279191388'
           ]
           for url1 in url:
               yield scrapy.Request(url=url1, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
     for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="rba--category-page"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[6]/a'):
         full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
         yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_item)



from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings`enter code here`

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    #enter code here

process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
process.stop()
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working. Are you getting errors, or no output, or something else?

Comment: For 1st method I tried, getting something like this if I open the html file created,

Node : dc1vplfry05.rbauction.net Build : 392 Revision : 022820191048
This field {0} is required. {0} is invalid. {0} can only contain letters [a-z]. {0} can only contain letters and numbers. {0} must be a number. {0} can only contain numbers [0-9]. {0} must be a valid password. {0} must be a valid email address. {0} must be a valid URL. {0} must be a valid date of the format YYYY-MM-DD. {0} must be at least {1} characters. {0} must be no more than {1} characters.

Comment: For all other methods using requests and others, Web page source (which we get using F12 button) is totally different than what I m getting as html code generated. So not able to find the proper classes or tags I need to extract.

Comment: It's because the page content is javascript generated. Spot network exchanges using developer tools in your browser and notice the several requests performed and trace where the content which you're after comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try looking into it.